# Changing background color using v-bind with condition method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to v-bind with condition to change bgcolor of my table row using my data in leavehr.is_read_hr == '0' as a sample.

```
  <template v-for="leavehr in leaveshr">
      <tr class="even">
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="Leavesub_chk" name="ids[]"  :data- 
           id="leavehr.leave_id"></td>
         <td class="tr_">@{{leavehr.lastname}}, @{{leavehr.firstname}}</td>
         <td>@{{leavehr.leave_start}}</td>
         <td>@{{leavehr.duration}} Day(s)</td>
         <td>
            <h4>
            <span v-if="leavehr.head == 'approved'"class="label-default label label- 
             success">Approved</span>
            <span v-else-if="leavehr.head == 'pending'"  class="label-default label 
             label-warning">Pending</span>
            <span v-else="leavehr.head == 'pending'"  class="label-default label 
             label-danger">Rejected</span>
            </h4>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h4>
              <span v-if="leavehr.hr == 'approved'"class="label-default label label- 
               success">Approved</span>
              <span v-else-if="leavehr.hr == 'pending'"  class="label-default label 
               label-warning">Pending</span>
              <span v-else="leavehr.hr == 'pending'"  class="label-default label 
               label-danger">Rejected</span>
            </h4>
       </td>
       <td>
         <a :href="'ViewsLeave/' + leavehr.leave_id" class="view-modal btn 
         btn-info btn-sm">
          view
            </a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </template>
```

i'm having a hard time to solve this. I'm not good using vue.js also. I don'y which one would i use. V-IF or V-BIND. What i really want to change the color when its not read. So the back-end is done. only the front-end to change color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html). Classes can be added conditionally:

```
<span class="label-default label"
 v-bind:class='{ "success": leavhr.hr == "label-success", "pending": leavhr.hr == "label-warning", "rejected": leavehr.hr == "label-danger" }'
 >{{leavehr.hr}}</span>
```

You may wish to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to map `leavehr.hr` to a human readable value.

Comment: I think i understand now. Can I do this to change my entire row to change its bgcolor?. like this v-bind:class w/ condition. But how can i put this like? v-bind:class='{"style:bgcolor = red ": leavehr.is_read == "0"}' . . .

Comment: Yes, you could add a conditional class onto the `tr` element instead.

Comment: <tr v-bind:class'{  "success" : leavehr.is_read_id == "0" , "danger": leaverhr.is_read_id == "1" }' > How bout this one sir?.

Comment: That looks like it should work (with the correct styles set up, obviously).

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. I appreciated your help. I guess i need to learn a lot. This vue.js helps me a lot creating dynamic features.